# why RECORD_AUDIO permission is required for video recording

Tags: android

In my application, video recording is done just by requesting CAMERA permission and STORAGE permission(for saving the recorded video) . and  RECORD_AUDIO permission is not required at all. and audio is also recorded with video captured. my question is: why this option in telegram needs Audio permission??[this is the option I choosed in telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeWZO.jpg)

[and this is RECORD_AUDIO permision request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYhFA.jpg)

Comment: `Telegram requests` only telegram developers know about it. `What is the difference between RECORD_AUDIO permission and CAMERA permission` did you check the documentation for that?

Answer (score 1):

Your application must request `CAMERA` permission to use a device camera but for recording audio with video capture, your application must request the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission too. Telegram request both permissions because it captures video and audio in video messages.